# implode input names from $_POST in php

Tags: php, implode

I am trying to implode inputnames from `$_POST` with commas and no comma at the end. I have been able to successfuly implode `$_POST` values but am unable to do the same for inputnames from `$_POST`. Please help

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
 $curry = "";
 foreach ($_POST as $name => $val)
 {
 $curry .= $name;
 }
 echo $curry;
 echo implode(",",(array_slice($_POST,0,-2))); //this works for value
 echo implode(',',$curry); // this doesnt work for input names
```

Comment: @T0xicCode gave a good code. But I just wonder what is the reason to do this transformation??? why do you need well prepared array with KEY=>VAL elements be splited into 2 strings? what is your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `$curry` isn't an array which you can implode! It is a string.

So if you change these lines:

```
$curry = "";
//...
$curry .= $name;
```

to this:

```
$curry = array();
//...
$curry[] = $name;
```

Then it is a array which you can implode.

Answer (score 0):

[`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) returns an array containing the keys of the input array. You'd use it as follow:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
 echo implode(",",(array_slice($_POST,0,-2)));
 echo implode(',',(array_slice(array_keys($_POST),0,-2)));
```